# How to find $p \in (0,1)$ that P is transient, null recorrent and positive recorrent?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider a Markov chain with space state $S = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$ and transition matrix given by

$$P_{i,j} = \left \{ \begin{matrix} qp^{j - i+1}, & \mbox{for }\mbox{ i $\ge$ 1 and $j \ge i - 1$} \\ qp^j, & \mbox{for }i = 0\mbox{ and }j\ge 0 \end{matrix} \right.$$

and $P_{i,j} = 0$ otherwise, where $0 < p = 1-q < 1$.
For each value of $p \in (0,1)$, determine whether the chain is transient, null
recurrent or positive recurrent, and in the last case find the invariant distribution. 
I started taking $\pi = (\pi_i:i \in S)$ as a invariant distribution ($\pi = \pi P$), and trying to show some relation between $\pi_i$ and some special series (resulted from the exercise calculus). Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: a typical approach: first verify that there is a single communicating class.  Then to check for transience/recurrence: make state 0 absorbing, and check to see whether it is visiting WP1 -- I'd suggest doing that with a basic geometric series inspired martingale argument.  But you haven't addressed any of this or even what tools you have at your disposal.

Comment: @user8675309 I've not studied martingale yet... How can I use it?